# curvature 2-form and Bianchi identity

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I was trying to show that the second Bianchi expressed in terms of curvature 2-form really related to the ordinary second Bianchi identity,

Let $\Theta = D^2$ be the curvature two form (where $D$ is the covariant derivative), we have the following Bianchi identity:
$$[D,\Theta] = 0 \tag{1}$$

which is defined as $[D,\Theta]s = D(\Theta(s)) -\Theta \wedge D(s)$ for $s\in \Gamma(TM)$.

We can prove that $\Theta(X)(Y,Z) = R(Y,Z)X$ with the $R(Y,Z)X = D_YD_Z X - D_ZD_YX -D_{[Y,Z]}X$, we have the following second Bianchi identity:

$$\nabla_{X} R(Y,Z)W + \nabla_{Z}R(X,Y)W + \nabla_{Y}R(Z,X)W = 0
\tag{2}$$

I have some difficulty in proving that $(1) = (2)$, the main difficulty may lies on the expression $\Theta\wedge D(s)$, I don't know how to compute :

$$(\Theta\wedge D(s))(X,Y,Z)$$

Comment: I suggest doing all of the calculations with respect to local coordinates.

Comment: thank you when proving something involve covariant derivative and curvature, it will be helpful to write everything in terms of local coordinate(or some special coordinate), however what confuse me is the notation $[D,\Theta]s = D(\Theta(s)) -\Theta \wedge D(s)
$

Comment: You should first figure out what $D$ and $\Theta$ look like in local coordinates.

Comment: thank you ,maybe I know what you mean now, and why commutator is defined in this way.